# Does mobile-first-indexing mean developing in a lower res?

Tags: mobile

I just got notification that my site is now in the mobile first index in Google.

So does this mean that I should change my developing and work at a lower resolution oprimarily and then check "just to make" that it looks OK at higher resolutions?

I would imagine that there's very few people looking at my website on a mobile device due to its nature.

Tablets and smaller PCs maybe though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got notified on Google Search Console.

I don't think that to optimize for it is to lower your website resolution.

Some basic optimization I might suggest are:

- Make your website responsive
- Avoid using heavy fonts and images
- You can declutter your mobile view from the desktop, do not worry if the content will be different, as long that it will still relevant to your desktop.
- Make sure your pages are crawlable by search engine robots (Check your javascript)

You can check this timely discussion about optimizing for mobile-first indexing 
https://www.propelrr.com/blog/questions-google-mobile-first-indexing